# Can `xs:element ref` reference subelement?

Tags: xml, xsd

Let's have following `Parent` type in namespace `parents`:

```
<xs:element name="Parent">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Child1" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Child2" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In other type in other namespace, we could reference that type, like:

```
<xs:element ref="parents:Parent" />
```

Is is also possible to reference the child element only (without bringing it to top level)? Something like:

```
<xs:element ref="parents:Parent.Child1" />
```

Not sure, how to qualify the parent/child relationship, tried `:`, `.`, `\` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you want to reference an element declaration using the ref="" syntax, then it has to be a global element declaration with a unique name.

If you want to reuse element declarations without making them global, there are other mechanisms such as named model groups (`xs:group`).

P.S. Trying to find out what works by guessing at possible syntax is a pretty inefficient strategy for any programming language, but is especially unlikely to be successful with a language as unintuitive as XSD.

Comment: Agreed. I was trying to find the definition for xs:element and its ref attrib and ended up with QName unable to find any other info than it's qualified by namespace...